# How to remove literal \n and \\n from strings using R

Tags: r, regex, stringr

After extracting texts from pdf files, my variables contain literal `\n` and `\\n`. How can I remove them? I have tried `form2_df$firm_new <- str_replace_all(form2_df$firm, "\\n", "")`. But it did nothing.

Here is my dput output:

```
structure(list(firm = c("\\n\\n        X, P.C.\\n\\n", "\\n\\n        \\\"Y & Company, CPA, PC\\n\\n", 
"\\n\\n        NGroup, Ltd LLP\\n\\n", "\\n\\n         247 ting, LLC\\n\\n"
), issuer_name = c("c(\"\\\\n                New Continent Ltd.\\\\n\\\\n               \", \"\\\\n                FellCorp.\\\\n\\\\n               \", \"\\\\n               Chain New  Ltd.\\\\n\\\\n               \", \"\\\\n                Fellazo Corp.\\\\n\\\\n               \", \"\\\\n                Seed Corp.\\\\n\\\\n               \", \"\\\\n                Greenland Technologies Horp.\\\\n\\\\n               \", \"\\\\n                Indoor \\\\n\\\\n               \", \"\\\\n                Packaging, Inc.\\\\n\\\\n               \", \"\\\\n                IT Tech Packaging, Inc.\\\\n\\\\n               \", \"\\\\n                Holdings, Inc.\\\\n\\\\n               \", \"\\\\n                PK Kirk Inc.\\\\n\\\\n               \", \"\\\\n                Planet Corp.\\\\n\\\\n               \", \"\\\\n                Art Co., Ltd.\\\\n\\\\n               \", \"\\\\n                Resource Group\\\\n\\\\n               \", \"\\\\n\\\\n\\\\n            \", \"\\\\n\\\\n\\\\n               \")", 
"c(\"\\\\n\\\\n\\\\n              \", \"\\\\n\\\\n\\\\n               \", \"\\\\n\\\\n\\\\n                \")", 
"c(\"\\\\n\\\\n\\\\n              \", \"\\\\n\\\\n\\\\n              \", \"\\\\n\\\\n\\\\n               \", \"\\\\n\\\\n\\\\n               \")", 
"c(\"\\\\n\\\\n\\\\n                \", \"\\\\n\\\\n\\\\n                \", \"\\\\n\\\\n\\\\n                \", \"\\\\n\\\\n\\\\n                \")"
), num = c("c(\"\\\\n                1641398                                                               \", \"\\\\n                1659207                                                               \", \"\\\\n                1641398                                                           \", \"\\\\n                1659207                                                           \", \"\\\\n                1524829                                                           \", \"\\\\n                1735041                                                           \", \n\"\\\\n                1572565                                                           \", \"\\\\nC, P.C.: Annual Report                                                                                                                 OB 2 (v. 2.10) Page 7 / 24\\\\n                1358190                                                           \", \"\\\\n                1358190                                                            \", \"\\\\n                1816172                                                            \", \n\"\\\\n                1833372                                                            \", \"\\\\n                1117057111                                                         \", \"\\\\n                1491487                                                            \", \"\\\\n                1409431                                                            \", \"\\\\n                                                                      \", \"\\\\n             0000857455                                                           \", \n\"\\\\n                                                                        \", \"\\\\n                0000857455                                                         \", \"\\\\n                0001090102                                                         \", \"\\\\n                0000702238                                                         \", \"\\\\n                0000857455                                                      \", \"\\\\n                0001090102                                                      \", \n\"\\\\n                0000702238                                                      \", \"\\\\n                0001364891                                                      \", \"\\\\n                1753567                                                         \", \"\\\\nC, P.C.: Annual Report                                                                                                                OB Form 2 (v. 2.10) Page 11 / 24\\\\n                861354                                                          \", \n\"\\\\n               861354                                                                \")", 
"c(\"\\\\n                                                                                      d\\\\n                                                                                      e\\\\n                                                                                      f\\\\n                                                                                      g\", \"\\\\n                                                                        d\\\\n                                                                        e\\\\n                                                                        f\\\\n                                                                        g\\\\n                                                                        c\", \n\"\\\\n                                                                         c\\\\n                                                                         d\\\\n                                                                         e\\\\n                                                                         f\\\\n                                                                         g\")", 
"c(\"\\\\n                                                                                      d\\\\n                                                                                      e\\\\n                                                                                      f\\\\n                                                                                      g\\\\n                                                                                      c\", \"\\\\n                                                                                     c\\\\n                                                                                     d\\\\n                                                                                     e\\\\n                                                                                     f\\\\n                                                                                     g\", \n\"\\\\n                                                                      d\\\\n                                                                      e\\\\n                                                                      f\\\\n                                                                      g\\\\n                                                                      c\", \"\\\\n                                                                      e\\\\n                                                                      f\\\\n                                                                      g\\\\n                                                                      c\", \n\"\\\\n                                                                                c\\\\n                                                                                d\\\\n                                                                                e\\\\n                                                                                f\\\\n                                                                                g\\\\n                                                                                b\", \n\"\\\\n                                                                                b\\\\n                                                                                c\\\\n                                                                                d\\\\n                                                                                e\\\\n                                                                                f\\\\n                                                                                g\", \n\"\\\\n                                                                                d\\\\n                                                                                e\\\\n                                                                                f\\\\n                                                                                g\\\\n                                                                                b\", \"\\\\n                                                                                c\\\\n                                                                                d\\\\n                                                                                e\\\\n                                                                                f\\\\n                                                                                g\\\\n                                                                                b\"\n)", 
"c(\"\\\\n                                                                                       \", \"\\\\n                                                                                      \", \"\\\\n                                                                          \", \"\\\\n                                                                         \", \"\\\\n                                                                                    \", \"\\\\n                                                                                        \"\n)"
), number_of_accountants = c("7\\n\\n", "1                               d\\n                                                                                                                                         e\\n                                                                                                                                         g\\n                                                                                                                                         c g\\n                                                                                                                                         f f\\n                                                                                                                                           c\\n                                                                                                                                           e\\n                                                                                                                                           d\\n\\n                                                                                                                                         CA CR\\n", 
"5                             d\\n                                                                                                                                        c g\\n                                                                                                                                        g\\n                                                                                                                                        e\\n                                                                                                                                        f c\\n                                                                                                                                          e\\n                                                                                                                                          f\\n                                                                                                                                          d\\n\\n                                                                                                                                       CA CR\\n", 
"3\\n\\n"), firm_new = c("\\n\\n        WC, P.C.\\n\\n", "\\n\\n        \\\"John Company, PC\\n\\n", 
"\\n\\n        BM Group, Ltd LLP\\n\\n", "\\n\\n          Continuous LLC\\n\\n"
)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Answer (score 1):

I took the liberty to clean more than you asked but I am not sure if it helps or makes it more difficult to understand the text.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  #Remove "\\n", "c()" along with leading and trailing commas
  mutate(across(.fns = ~trimws(gsub('["\\nc()]', '', .), whitespace = "[ \t\r\n,]")), 
  #Replace more than 2 spaces with a single space.
         across(.fns = ~gsub('\\s+', ' ', .)))


 #  firm      issuer_name                           num                               number_of_accoun… firm_new  
#  <chr>     <chr>                                 <chr>                             <chr>             <chr>     
#1 X, P.C.   "New Cotiet Ltd. , FellCorp. , Chai … "1641398 , 1659207 , 1641398 , 1… 7                 WC, P.C.  
#2 Y & Comp… ""                                    "d e f g, d e f g , d e f g"      1 d e g g f f e … Joh Compa…
#3 NGroup, … ""                                    "d e f g , d e f g, d e f g , e … 5 d g g e f e f … BM Group,…
#4 247 tig,… ""                                    ""                                3                 Cotiuous …
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Can you care to explain what `.fns` is? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: `?across` has two main arguments. `.cols` and `.fns` where `.cols` is the columns that you want to apply the function (`.fns`) to. By default `.cols` applies to all the columns in the dataframe (so I don't specify `.cols`), `.fns` is the function to be applied. So here we are applying `trimws` and `gsub` function to every column of the dataframe.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. One caveat though: gsubing `"\\nc()` also removes all `n`s from strings.